# Springboot 3 ManytoMany request payload serializing correctly

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot 3, Java 21 restful API and JPA with mysql and I've got a problem with receiving the request.

I'm working with a Many to many relationship with the models `User` and `Invoice` as follows:

User

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User extends Audit {
    ....
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"users", "handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "users_invoices",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="invoice_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "invoice_id"})}
    )
    private List<Invoice> invoices;

    .....
}
```

Invoice

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "invoices")
public class Invoice extends Audit {
    
    ....

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"invoices", "handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "invoices")
    private List<User> users;

    ....
}
```

The MySQL tables are created successfully:

- [users table img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmSSk.png)
- [invoices table img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz5eg.png)
- [users invoices table img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lxqh.png)

I have the following controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/invoices")
public class InvoiceController {
    ....
    
    @PostMapping("")
    @Transactional
    public Invoice saveInvoice(@RequestBody Invoice invoice){
        System.out.println(invoice.toString());
        Invoice newInvoice = invoiceService.createInvoice(invoice);
        return newInvoice;
    }
}
```

What I'd expect to happen: user_id or user object is serialized on my request to the endpoint.

What happens: when hitting my endpoint I receive my Invoice payload without my user_id which causes that I cannot create the relationship between my user and invoice classes.

My postman request body is as follows [Postman Request img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOC2A.png) (where `{{id}}` is my UUID if of a user):

```
{
    "user_id":  "{{id}}",
    "amount": 1150,
    "status": "PENDING"
}
```

When receiving the request body I get the following object:

```
Invoice(id=null, users=null, amount=1150, status=PENDING, date=null)
```

I tried changing the body of my request to have a user object `"user_id": [Object user]`, and also changing user_id for `"users": ["{{id}}"]` without any luck.

Any help or insight will be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd start with splitting your DTOs (your request body) and db Entities, then it'll be much more clear what is happening. Also, share contents of your `createInvoice` method.
Let's say you'll have InvoiceDTO - it'll have list of user ids. Based on that, you'll (inside your service layer) fetch Users and add them to the Invoice. Don't forget to do it on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, it will probably be much clearer if you separate DTO and Entity layer.

The problem is not that request payload is not serialized correctly. The "problem" is that Spring Boot doesn't "automatically" translate user id's to user entities, does not add the new invoice for each of the users in ids and does not add the users to the entity. This is still responsibility of us - developers.

### InvoiceDTO

To be used as `@RequestBody`:

```
public class InvoiceDTO {
    // getters/setters/constructors
    private long amount;
    private List<Long> userIds;
    ...
}
```

### Invoice

```
public void addUser(User user) {
    users.add(user);
    user.getInvoices().add(this);
}
```

### InvoiceService

```
@Transactional
public Invoice saveInvoice(InvoiceDTO invoiceDto) {
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.setAmount(invoiceDto.getAmount());
    invoice.setUsers(new ArrayList<>());
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAllById(invoiceDTO.getUserIds());
    for(User user : users) {
        invoice.addUser(user);
    }
    return invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
}
```

This should then work with request body

```
{
    "userIds":  [1,2,3],
    "amount": 1150,
    ...
}
```

You'll need get around potential circular dependencies/lazy initialization/transactions issues. For more details I'd recommend consulting [this blog post by Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

You could make it work without introducing InvoiceDTO - but then you'd e.g. need to add `@Transient` on the Invoice's fields that are not to be saved to database (and are used only in request body).

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Now I understand that Spring Boot doesn't automatically handle the translation of user IDs to user entities and the associated tasks of adding new invoices for each user in the provided IDs, as well as updating the users in the entity. Also, I will added the DTOs to my requests